# CasC with Bamboo

Tags: bamboo, casc, yaml

While trying to get a clear picture how to setup a seamless CasC (Configuration as Code) build and deployment plan management, I have to admit that I get quite puzzled.

Is the following (subjective) *ideal scenario* possible?

- Users can manage their plans as code or via UI as YAML
- Plan changes in UI result in a commit to the CasC code base (YAML as well)

In the meantime, my impressions are that just pieces of that are possible but no integraton setup yet:

1. Admins can manually export (and import?) plan configurations as YAML via UI
2. Bamboo Specs allow Java language coding of plans.

Looks like #1 is too limited (possibly usage of REST API could change that? But still you'd need admin rights) and #2 will be overdesigned for most cases.

Anybody has a solution for the (subjective) *ideal scenario*?

Answer (score 2):

[This slide share](https://www.slideshare.net/GoAtlassian/configuration-as-code-in-bamboo) gives an idea how to handle CasC in Bamboo.

The presenter advocates to use yaml, but according to him there are also downsides.